# Visual Studio update. Opened a solution in Windows Form VB and there are no controls in my toolbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, controls, toolbox

I updated the VS studio application and when I tried to start a new solution for a visual basic windows form design the controls were missing from my toolbox. It says at the bottom "There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox."

In Right Clicking the toolbox I used the following options:

'Reset Toolbox' does nothing.

'Show all' lists lots of shaded out controls under 'Dialog Editor' and 'Ribbon Editor' but they can not be accessed.

'Choose items' allows me to select items like a textbox, but afterwards I am told:

"The following controls were successfully added but are not enabled in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer."

I tried regressing to the previous version. I tried repairing the application. I tried opening previous solutions where the controls were working, and they no longer were there. I tried deleting and reinstalling the application from my program. I have reported an issue under the help menu selection with no response. I contacted my teacher, and he does not know what is wrong with it.

I have tried other troubleshooting from everything I found on the internet including information already in this reddit forum, and nothing has helped.  This is one thing I tried already: https://thinkaboutit.be/2012/10/my-toolbox-is-empty/

I am a student with upcoming assignments, and I need my Visual Studio Windows Form Designer for Visual Basic to have a working toolbox with working controls. HELP!

Comment: resetting the toolbobox worked for me but you can try alos https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022---172---Toolbox-has-no-tools-fo/10040667?q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.2%5D&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem&sort=votes

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check the following directory where also have the .tbd files.

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_dbab3d69
```